# Function to transform methods into functions that take this as their first argument

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

The initial problem was splitting a string using a delimiter in JS and then removing whitespace from both sides of each result. The solution to this looked like this:

```
var mystring = "First thing, Second thing";
var things = mystring.split(",").map(function(s) { return s.trim(); });
// things is now ["First thing", "Second thing"]
```

This made me think if there's a way to write this without creating an anonymous (or named) function to contain trim. How do I write a function `unmethod` such that

```
mystring.split(",").map(unmethod(String.prototype.trim));
// returns ["First thing", "Second thing"]
```

returns an array that is the same as `things`. In other words, how do I transform some method that expects `this` to be bound into a function that takes one variable and operates on that variable the same way the method would on `this`.

Also, what if I wanted to pass arguments to the method? For example, if I wanted to map `split` over an array of strings I'd need a way to pass it the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to pass a method to `Array.prototype.map`:

```
var myarray = ["A|B", "C|D"];

function applyM(key) {
  return function (args) {
    return function (o) {
      return o[key].apply(o, args);
    };
  };
};

var split = applyM("split");

myarray.map(applyM("split")(["|"]));
myarray.map(split(["|"]));
```

`String.prototype.split` remains a method, you just apply it, hence the name `applyM`. By separating `key` from `args` you gain flexibility.

**EDIT:**

The problem with `applyM` is, that it handles nullary methods with an unnecessary call. Since objects are implicit arguments of methods, nullary methods are useful. Due to this, `args` becomes an optional parameter. This is an example of why I don't like optional parameters or variadic functions.

I see three options:

1. `applyM` becomes a binary function `applyM(key, args)` in which `args` is optional (and loses its partial applicability)
2. there is an additional `applyM0` for nullary methods (and inflates the api)
3. `applyM` becomes a stateful function (and loses a bit of its conciseness)

Implementation of #3:

```
function applyM(arity, key) {
  return function (xs) {
    if (xs.length <= arity) {
      return function (o) {
        return o[key].apply(o, xs);
      };
    }

    return xs[key]();
  };
};

var a = ["A|B", "C|D"];
var split = applyM(1, "split");
var lower = applyM(0, "toLowerCase");
var includes = applyM(2, "includes");

a.map(split(["|"])); // [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
a.map(lower); // ["a|b", "c|d"]
a.map(includes(["A", 0])); // [true, false]
```

Comment: Ah, that's cool! I like the fact you don't need to type in the whole class name to get the method and are fetching it from the object instead. I don't see the benefit in wrapping it in another function to get the arguments though. It's nice when the method does take arguments, but in case it doesn't (e.g. trim) you have to have an extra empty application (i.e. without any arguments). Does that actually give you any extra flexibility?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. You would have to pass the arity explicitly to avoid this. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: With additional flexibility I mean the possibility to partially apply `applyM`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by defining `unmethod` as follows:

```
function unmethod(f, args) {
    return function(x) {
        return f.apply(x, args);
    };
};
```

The `args` argument is optional, so it will work as described in the question. In this case the extra arguments can be passed like this:

```
var myarray = ["A|B", "C|D"];
myarray.map(unmethod(String.prototype.split, ["|"]))
// returns [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
var unmethod = function (callback) {
    return function (s) {
        return callback.apply(s);
    }
};
```